# Not Returning all values from billpayment check table from Quickbooks?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm using PHP Quickbooks dev kit 2.0. When I try to fetch all bill payment checks from the quickbooks db, some fields like BankAccountRefListID, BankAccountRefFullName, etc are not returned.

This is my request code:-

```
function _quickbooks_billpaymentcheck_query_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <BillPaymentCheckQueryRq>

            </BillPaymentCheckQueryRq>  
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
}
```

What may be the problem?

You can check my previous question in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146720/fetching-all-bill-payment-check-from-quickbooks-database`

Here I described my code.

Comment: first offall it could be values of parameters you send and not showing to us :-)

Comment: when you call a function `_quickbooks_billpaymentcheck_query_request` you pass parameters `$requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale` and we are here have no idea what is that except names of variables, but they all could be `null` or `zero` or `''` so first of all when you ask questions it would better to show us proves of values of those values

Comment: Actually Iam using PHP Quickbooks dev kit. In it Fetching customer records works fine with this code. But when I tried to write code for fetching bill payment checks it is returning some values only. some imp fields are missing?? so my question is   any error in my request code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. The problem is that I got a resonse from xml like this:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<BillPaymentCheckQueryRs requestID="99" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info"  statusMessage="Status OK">
<BillPaymentCheckRet>

 <TxnID>49-1421654713</TxnID>
 <TimeCreated>2015-01-19T12:05:13+04:00</TimeCreated>
 <TimeModified>2015-01-19T12:05:13+04:00</TimeModified>
  <EditSequence>1421654713</EditSequence>
  <TxnNumber>18</TxnNumber>
  <PayeeEntityRef>
 <ListID>80000004-1421654642</ListID>
 <FullName>tobs</FullName>
  </PayeeEntityRef>
 <APAccountRef>
 <ListID>80000023-1418466302</ListID>
<FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
  </APAccountRef>
<TxnDate>2015-01-19</TxnDate>
<BankAccountRef>
<ListID>8000002D-1421653817</ListID>
<FullName>ENBD</FullName>
 </BankAccountRef>
 <Amount>2000.00</Amount>
 <RefNumber>123</RefNumber>
  <IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
  <AppliedToTxnRet>
 <TxnID>46-1421654678</TxnID>
  <TxnType>Bill</TxnType>
 <TxnDate>2015-01-19</TxnDate>
  <BalanceRemaining>0.00</BalanceRemaining>
  <Amount>2000.00</Amount>
  </AppliedToTxnRet>
   </BillPaymentCheckRet>
  </BillPaymentCheckQueryRs>
  </QBXMLMsgsRs>
  </QBXML>
```

So In this xml  tag is child of . so we have to fetch the value like this:-

```
$BankAccountRefListID=$BillPaymentCheck->getChildDataAt('BillPaymentCheckRet BankAccountRef ListID');
```

In this function we have to pass value like this first main parent, then after space child & last the attribute. By doing like this only we can fetch values correctly.
So my response function finally will be like:-

```
    function _quickbooks_billpaymentcheck_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   

       $Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
       $errnum = 0;
       $errmsg = '';
        if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
        {
        $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
     $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/BillPaymentCheckQueryRs');
    foreach ($List->children() as $BillPaymentCheck)
        {

$TxnDateMacro=$BillPaymentCheck->getChildDataAt('BillPaymentCheckRet TxnDateMacro');
 $BankAccountRefListID=$BillPaymentCheck->getChildDataAt('BillPaymentCheckRet BankAccountRef ListID');  
  $BankAccountRefFullName=$BillPaymentCheck->getChildDataAt('BillPaymentCheckRet BankAccountRef FullName');  
   }
     }

    return true;
 }
```